# Update K8S container's imageid whitout change image's name or tag

Tags: kubernetes

In my deployment.yaml .the image is assigned like

```
- image: nexus.company.local:5000/company-ubuntu-32bit:2.0
```

In nexus, I update the image,but didn't change name and tag.
I want to use the new image in k8s pod.So I try to use

```
imagePullPolicy: "Always" + delete the old pod
```

Now on the node, docker images can show the new hash of image.
And in dashboard,I can see the event "pull image" successfully.
But

```
kubectl get pod -n k8s-demo k8s-pod-build-32-d4794d44-zrgvh -o json
```

show that the new created pod is still using old image hash id.

How can I update the image without change the image's name or tag?

uupdate the shows:

```
kubectl get pod -n k8s-demo k8s-pod-build-32-6fbb6bf5cc-dtg4f -o json
"containerStatuses": [
            {
                "containerID": "docker://ef57cbdf31256556fbeda5df4247591ea74ddb71ca0aec512278079e6badc201",
                "image": "nexus.company.local:5000/e7bld-cdc-32bit:2.0",
                "imageID": "docker-pullable://nexus.company.local:5000/e7bld-cdc-32bit@sha256:45f6b42ab2f7629cf8032c09c78ccf7627ca6e71d5c15173f81217100f87eecb",
```

and the docker image on node:

```
docker images
REPOSITORY                                   TAG                 IMAGE ID       CREATED             SIZE
nexus.company.local:5000/e7bld-cdc-32bit   2.0                 49889fd96652        4 days ago          1.29GB
```

45f6b42ab2f76 AND 49889fd96652 is different.

I use local env,and the kubectl version

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.2", GitCommit:"c97fe5036ef3df2967d086711e6c0c405941e14b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-10-15T19:18:23Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.2", GitCommit:"c97fe5036ef3df2967d086711e6c0c405941e14b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-10-15T19:09:08Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

docker images --digests

```
REPOSITORY                                   TAG                 DIGEST                                                                    IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
nexus.company.local:5000/e7bld-cdc-32bit   2.0                 sha256:45f6b42ab2f7629cf8032c09c78ccf7627ca6e71d5c15173f81217100f87eecb   49889fd96652        5 days ago          1.29GB
```

Comment: What is the output of `kubectl get pod -n k8s-demo k8s-pod-build-32-d4794d44-zrgvh -o json`? How did you decide it was using old image?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubernetes how to make Deployment to update image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366192/kubernetes-how-to-make-deployment-to-update-image)

Comment: ...but the best practice I've seen is to give a unique tag to each build (maybe have your CI system tag builds with a commit ID or date stamp); then this isn't a problem, plus you can easily roll back if a build doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using On-Prem or local env? What K8s version?

Comment: @Shashank V ,I found 45f6b42ab2f76 is the digest and 49889fd96652 is image id.So maybe it update successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing docker `image id` and it's `digest` which are not the same thing. `image id` is the hash of the JSON config of the local image. `digest` is the hash of registry manifest.

```
kubectl get pod -n k8s-demo k8s-pod-build-32-6fbb6bf5cc-dtg4f -o json
"containerStatuses": [
            {
                "containerID": "docker://ef57cbdf31256556fbeda5df4247591ea74ddb71ca0aec512278079e6badc201",
                "image": "nexus.company.local:5000/e7bld-cdc-32bit:2.0",
                "imageID": "docker-pullable://nexus.company.local:5000/e7bld-cdc-32bit@sha256:45f6b42ab2f7629cf8032c09c78ccf7627ca6e71d5c15173f81217100f87eecb"
```

`45f6b42ab2f7629cf8032c09c78ccf7627ca6e71d5c15173f81217100f87eecb` here is the digest.

```
docker images
REPOSITORY                                   TAG                 IMAGE ID       CREATED             SIZE
nexus.company.local:5000/e7bld-cdc-32bit   2.0                 49889fd96652        4 days ago          1.29GB
```

`49889fd96652` here is the image id.

If you want to see the digest of a local image, you can use

`docker inspect --format='{{index .RepoDigests 0}} <image_name>'`

`docker inspect --format='{{index .RepoDigests 0}}  nexus.company.local:5000/e7bld-cdc-32bit:2.0` in your case.

Comment: docker inspect --format='{{.RepoDigests}}' 49889fd96652 -------shows ----->45f6b42ab2f7629cf8032c09c78ccf7627ca6e71d5c15173f81217100f87eecb-----does it mean update successfully?

Comment: Yes. The digest matches.