# Helmfile Sync With The Same Image Tag

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helmfile

I'm currently facing an issue with Kubernetes deployments using Helmfile. I employ `helmfile sync` to deploy changes to Kubernetes. While doing so, I aim to deploy my Docker image tagged with the PR number, for instance, `myservice:pr-20`.

The challenge arises when I push new commits to the PR, and the image updates while preserving the same image tag. Consequently, when I trigger 'helmfile sync,' I observe the operation through the following command:

`helm history myservice --namespace mynamespace`

Here is the output

```
91          Wed Dec  6 13:01:23 2023    superseded  my-application-0.1  0.1         Upgrade complete
92          Wed Dec  6 22:23:31 2023    deployed    my-application-0.1  0.1         Upgrade complete
```

However, pods do not get restarted and because of that, I can't the changes in the PR which leads to not reflecting changes on the deployed environment. Any insights or suggestions on resolving this matter would be greatly appreciated. Should I use `--force` ?

Comment: You should use a different image tag for each build.  In general, Kubernetes will only take action if the text content of a resource changes; so you had a Deployment that wanted one replica of `myservice:pr-20`, and it already exists, so the cluster doesn't do anything.  As you step up the stack to Helm and Helmfile, the same rules apply, what's trying to be installed is identical to what's in the cluster so nothing happens.

Comment: [Kubernetes how to make Deployment to update image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366192/kubernetes-how-to-make-deployment-to-update-image) doesn't specifically discuss Helm/Helmfile but it's the same case of a Deployment wanting a different image for the same image name.